# Using the spread operator to change the style of a React component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to use the spread operator to affect the style of a React component, but it doesn't appear to work...

```
const newProps = { ...this.props, color: 'red' };

return (
  <SU_Table.Cell {...newProps}>
    {this.props.children}
  </SU_Table.Cell>
);
```

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to make the change in this way?

Comment: show us what is inside this.props ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: Is `SU_Table.Cell` from some library? Maybe you want to give your new object as the `style` prop?

Comment: I wonder what happens when you put a console.log({props}); inside the render method() of SU_Table.Cell component?

Comment: Yes, it's Semantic UI...

Comment: [The `style` prop seems to be working fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/p55ypjkjnq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `<SU_Table.Cell />` Component expects normal-named props (style for example) then this approach *should* work. if it doesn't is there any error messages you are receiving in your console?

```js
// lets say "props" looks like this
{
  fontSize: 12,
  children: [],
  somethingUnrelated: '@123123sadasd',
  text: 'Cell text'
}

class Table extends Component {
  render () {
    // the spreading of this.props will be applying unRelated properties to the Object
    // const newProps = { ...this.props, style: { color: 'red' } }
    // this spreading of this.props would also put the property 'children' into your
    // newProps Object and then ultimately into your SU_Table.Cell instantiation as an
    // attribute.
    
    // only taking what you want from props is more concise and readable.
    const { fontSize, text, children } = this.props
    const style = { fontSize, color: 'red' }
    const cellProps = { text, style }
    
    return (
      <>
        <SU_Table.Cell {...cellProps}>
          {children}
        </SU_Table.Cell>
        
        //<SU_Table.Cell text="Cell text" style={{fontSize: 12, color: 'red'}}>
        //  []
        //</SU_Table.Cell>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: ok so the API for this `SU_Table.Cell` what prop does it expect in order to style itself?

Comment: it also depends what is inside `this.props` right? if you have let's say `this.props.fontSize = 12;`

Comment: I think the spreading of props into this Object is abit hazardous. you're going to end up passing things you may not want (`children`) as that is already being referenced twice (once in the spread of newProps and also as actual children of SU_Table.Cell)

Comment: So, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: @jnoweb how about now?

Comment: Yes, this now works...thanks! Do you think this the most ideal way to approach this problem though? ))

Comment: It depends, i guess you are rendering quite a few Cells ? if you are and those cells have shared props then it makes sense to have a `commonProps` variable (maybe in place of your `newProps` variable) for me destructuring the props Object is more readable for me and negates any un-necessary props (`somethingUnrelated`) What are your end goals?

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure what is `SU_Table.Cell`.
But maybe try this?

```
const newProps = { ...this.props, color: 'red' };

return (
  <SU_Table.Cell styleProps={...newProps}>
    {this.props.children}
  </SU_Table.Cell>
);
```

And then you need to use `styleProps` on the actual Node element inside `SU_Table.Cell`

```
const SU_Table.Cell = (props) => {
     return (<div style={props.styleProps}> </div>)
}
```